# Preview image from URL - like Facebook

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, hyperlink, meteor

When you post a link on Facebook, it grabs an image from that page as a preview.

I'd like to be able to do the same! We're creating a link sharing website with Meteor, and want the user to be able to paste a link, and the image be rendered in the list.

Any ideas? Doesn't need to be Meteor specific at this stage!

Comment: So you want to grab the first image on the page from the url thats posted?

Comment: Go through this tutorial http://www.9lessons.info/2010/06/facebook-like-extracting-url-data-with.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by Sarath in his comment you have to scrape the webpage and look for the information you need (title, META desc, an image) by using a regex for example. 
I would suggest to look for [META OG tags](http://ogp.me/) already used by many websites or, if not available, Schema.org micro data.

I think that some tools like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) could be helpful as it allows you to get the content of a webpage and even generate screen capture of this page.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume and Sarath, that's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

To add an image when someone clicks on share/like etc, you can set the image for that page with

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yourdomain.com/link/to/image" />
```

When somebody shares it, it will use that image. You can also set titles and more:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#selfhosted-creating